# How can I disable default users "user" and "admin" in buildroot?

Tags: user-accounts, buildroot

I'm using [buildroot](https://buildroot.org/) for an embedded product. I've added my own password-protected user via the [`BR2_ROOTFS_USERS_TABLES`](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#customize-users) option, and that's working fine.

Problem: buildroot continues to add `user` and `admin` users to the system, and they have no passwords. These are not part of the skeleton file system, but seem to be explicitly added during the build process, although darned if I can figure out where. Plus, even when I disable `BR2_TARGET_ENABLE_ROOT_LOGIN`, I'm still allowed to login as root.

How can I get rid of the default `user` and `admin` users? Alternatively, how can I set their passwords to something long and unguessable?

**Edit:** I just discovered that removing

```
BR2_TARGET_ENABLE_ROOT_LOGIN=y
```

from my `BR2_TARGET_ENABLE_ROOT_LOGIN` file isn't enough; the file has to include the line

```
# BR2_TARGET_ENABLE_ROOT_LOGIN is not set
```

... or the built `.config` file will still have `BR2_TARGET_ENABLE_ROOT_LOGIN=y` in it. But, even after I corrected this and did a clean rebuild, my resulting system still has no-password `root` logins, and both `user` and `admin` accounts with empty passwords.

Comment: Recursive grep is your friend.  It might take a few minutes, but you should be able to find where this is coming from.  Look both for the user id's and the passwd / shadow file origins.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Good idea, but been there/done that. There are 1300 "user"s in the codebase, and although there are only 31 "admin"s, none look apropos. And, the user IDs are almost certainly calculated from a base of 1000, and there are 2762 "1000"s.

Answer (score 2):

Have you done a clean build after disabling `BR2_TARGET_ENABLE_ROOT_LOGIN`?  I've always had problems trying to rebuild the skeleton package.

I've never seen a buildroot user named `user` or `admin`.  A grep through my buildroot packages also doesn't show any such user defined:
`awk '/define.*_USERS/,/endef/' package/*/*mk`  Can you run the same on your system and be sure to include any custom *.mk files you have?

Is it possible that `user` and `admin` are leftover from earlier attempts to create your own password-protected users?  Again, a clean build would help that.

Comment: Nice awk script! Unfortunately, it didn't find anything relevant.

Comment: As I describe in the new edit to my questions, it turns out I hadn't really turned off `BR2_TARGET_ENABLE_ROOT_LOGIN=y`. But, even after I did it correctly, a clean build still has `root`, `user` and `admin` accounts. (Bummer.)

Answer (score 2):

As observed in other answers, nothing in Buildroot adds `admin` or `user` users.

Users may be added to `/etc/passwd` in four places:

- The file `/etc/passwd` in the skeleton. If you have a custom skeleton, it may come from there.
- The users table that is constructed from packages and filesystems. You can see what is in there in `output/build/buildroot-fs/users_table.txt` (or, in your old version of Buildroot, in `output/build/_users_table.txt`).
- A file `/etc/passwd` that is present in your custom filesystem overlay.
- Any manipulations done on `/etc/passwd` by a post-build script.

It is also possible (though not intended) that a package updates `/etc/passwd` directly. If that is the case, you will see it appear in `output/build/packages-file-list.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're using the official Buildroot ? The official Buildroot has a default `/etc/passwd` at https://git.buildroot.org/buildroot/tree/system/skeleton/etc/passwd and it doesn't contain any `admin` or `user` users.

Comment: I'm using Buildroot 2016.11.3, and yes, the skeleton `/etc/passwd` file doesn't have `admin` or `user` users. However, these users are somehow added during the build process.